# line aligning, HTML, CSS JAVASCRIPT

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am making an application for an android phone using eclipse, I want to be able to have a label and a text field in one line or and a label and a checkbox in one line.
I have used the following codes for this purpose, but it doesnt work. you should also know that i am using jquery-mobile platform and I test the codes on an android phone.

SO any help would be appreciated!!

```
<p class="label_field_pair">
  <label for="foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" id="foo" />
</p>
```

and the following css:

```
p.label_field_pair {

  clear: both;

  float: none;

}

p.label_field_pair label {

  clear: left;

  display: block;

  float: left;

  text-align: right;

  width: 100px;

}

p.label_field_pair input {

  clear: right;

  float: left;

  margin-left: 10px;

  width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this issue is only happening on mobile devices?

Comment: I only tested this on an android device.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean when you say it doesn't work? And while I'm at it, what is the screen width of the android device?

Comment: well, i am trying to get a check box and a label in one line horizontally. so i used the code from above. but I didnt get what I expected. the device is 392 x 653.

Comment: My best guess is that you have some additional padding and margins elsewhere and you just don't have enough width for them to remain on the same line. If you look at this on a more traditional-sized screen, you'll see they line up. On such a narrow screen, you're going to have to start looking at either reducing some margins/padding or reducing the width of your label and/or input. As it stands now, just the label and input take up 310px of width.

Comment: Are you using the jQueryMobile library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid floats when you can. The implementation of inline-block is pretty good among browsers, especially if you include the -moz hack for older versions of FF. However, I don't know if it behaves in your mobile browser… Does it?

**HTML**

```
<p class="label_field_pair">
  <label for='foo'>Foo: </label>
  <input type="text" id="foo" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p.label_field_pair { display:block; }
p.label_field_pair label { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block; width:100px; }
p.label_field_pair  input { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block; width:200px; }
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `inline-block`. Labels and input elements are inline by default, so they will be on one line automatically when you don't apply any styles at all.

Comment: Ouch, true… In that case you can also write the HTML like this `<label>Lorem: <input type='text' name='ipsum' /></label>` to get rid of the for attribute.